# Create table in Mysql via using data from Microsoft Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010

1. the problem: i want MySQL to read data from Access database on real-time, which means whenever the data is updated in Access, i can click refresh in mysql to update the table.
   Not the other way around, i know that access can link to mysql database on real-time. but that's not what i want.
   the reason why i need to have such connection is because, we have another app which can only export data into access on daily basis. so only the access file is refreshed.
2. I have tried to use ODBC server to export access table to mysql table. but that is not on real-time, if i updated any data in access table, the data will not refreshed in mysql.

Comment: You can only connect from ms access to mysql, not the other way around. However, if you change data a linked table in ms access, that should refresh the data in mysql as well.

Comment: As mentioned, MySQL doesn't have this functionality. You need to create a pipeline setup that will read from your access db and send the data to mysql in a timely manner. There are tools out there that does this stuff. Googling "automate replication from db to mysql" there are a lot of solutions out there. Here is one on above search for access: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/access-sync-mysql.rst